# How do I deploy/import war package into Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, import, package, deployment, war

I have looked through the help documentation in netbeans 6.5.1 but cannot find anything explicit explaining how to deploy/import a war package.

I know in Eclipse, it's as easy as right clicking in the Project Explorer >> select IMPORT >> WAR FILE.

However, I still am unable to find a solution for Netbeans.

Thankyou,
Jordan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you don't already have an ant or maven project for your web project?  If you did, you would just import a maven project or create a Web Free-Form Application and wire it up to your ant script.

I would unzip the war file, create a new web application with existing sources in netbeans and wire everything up using the wizard.

Answer (score 9):

posted elsewhere, thought i might post here too.

after some googling I've found the solution and here are the steps:

(tested using apache's ode.war in NetBeans 8.0)

1. unzip the war file
2. in the unzipped folder, you will see WEB-INF/, META-INF/, etc., create a sub-folder named web in the unzipped folder.
3. put everything else into web (now they will be web/WEB-INF/, web/js/, ...)
4. go to netbeans, **new project -> java web -> web application** with existing sources
5. pretty much just press next all the way through. voilà, it's done.

Answer (score 2):

1. Import the war project to eclipse.
2. Then import the eclipse project to netbeans

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have eclipse handy, just place the war file into the `webapps` folder of Tomcat, go to the `bin` folder of Tomcat and run `startup`. Tomcat will automatically extract the war file for you. Now go to the `webapps` folder and you'll find another folder there, with the same name as your war.

I couldn't find an option to import a war directly into Netbeans (*strange. Perhaps someone could create this feature and submit it as a patch to Netbeans*). The folder which gets extracted into the Tomcat folder can be used as the Netbeans project. It's advisable to copy it to some other folder first. Import by `File > New Project > Web application with existing sources`.

Eclipse has an option to export a war and include the sources with it too, so there's a chance that the source files are in the war too.